# Centering Lightbox from Revolution Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Revolution Slider. From that Slider I open a Lightbox.

The problem is the lightboxes' positions are all off. It seems that their top and left margins are fixed.

```
/*
set your slider's api name here
http://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/slider-settings/#api
*/
var api = revapi16;

/* ********************* */
/* no need to edit below */
/* ********************* */
window.hideRevNav = function() {

    jQuery('.tp-thumbs,' + 
           '.tparrows,' + 
           '.tp-bullets,' + 
           '.tp-tabs,' + 
           '.tp-open-lightbox').addClass('hide-rev-nav');

}

window.showRevNav = function() {

    jQuery('.tp-thumbs,' + 
           '.tparrows,' + 
           '.tp-bullets,' + 
           '.tp-tabs,' + 
           '.tp-open-lightbox').removeClass('hide-rev-nav');

}


jQuery(document).on('keyup', function(event) {

    if(event.keyCode === 27) {

        api.find('.active-revslide .close-lightbox').click();

    }

});
```

The CSS

```
/* hide default navigation while lightbox is open */
.rev_slider .hide-rev-nav {
    visibility: hidden !important
}
```

The lightboxes are 1480 in width and 960 height.

I need it to be absolute center.

Comment: Could you create a snippet?

Comment: Snippet from? Sorry first time posting here so not used to the vocabulary :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Create a [mcve], it will make helping you easier.

Comment: Thank you : )

Hm I am de designer of the website. The lightbox worked fine when using the first external url that was viewed in the lightbox. We now need another external url that need a bigger Lightbox.

I have not writen the code so I am afraid I will be at no use for cleaning up the code : (

Comment: is there more css? seems like there is something missing

Comment: that is all I got from the plugin we used but yeah I agree thier should be som more css there. possible it is added to the theme CSS